# Is it possible to stream a file on demand over SFTP, using .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, streaming, sftp

I want to transfer a file over SFTP, using .NET.  The problem I have is that, due to very strict security, I can never write this file to disk in our environment (meaning that I can't just upload it to SFTP, because then it will write the file to disk).  The client is already retrieving files and processing our files from SFTP, so I don't want them to have to change anything on their side.

I would guess that, if this is possible, I will have to use a third party library, so any solutions using a third party library could be acceptable.

Any ideas on whether this is possible, and if so, how it can be done?

Thanks :)

**NOTE**

Not sure from the one answer I was clear enough about the disk thing.  To clarify:
We're not allowed to write the file to disk in our environment and **this includes the FTP server**.

**NOTE**

It might be possible to configure our SFTP server (Crush FTP) not to write to disk (or at least to write the file to disk encrypted and send it decrypted).  This would mean that simply streaming to the correctly configured SFTP server could resolve the problem.

**My solution**

After considering the answers given and doing further research, my solution will probably be to use a third party library like http://sshnet.codeplex.com/, and configuring our [SFTP server](http://www.crushftp.com/crush7wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Advanced%20VFS) to encrypt the file before writing it to disk, and decrypt it when sending.

Comment: How you imagine to upload file which will not be saved in disk but client will access it via url?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe most third-party libraries work with Stream objects as a data source when uploading the data and you can use an instance of MemoryStream for this.

Comment: Thanks Eugene.  Do you understand that I want to stream the file to the client on demand, rather than uploading it, because we're not allowed to write the file to disk?

Comment: @StephenOberauer direction doesn't matter and the approach is the same in both cases: when downloading, you can either stream to MemoryStream instance or use some ReadRemoteFile() method (instead of WriteRemoteFile()) to get a chunk of data and write it where you need.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, based on the assumption that one also has to configure one's SFTP server not to write the file to disk, or to encrypt it when doing so.

Answer (score 1):

have you considered allowing the sftp client access to a ramdisk location?  write the file to the ramdisk, and let the client retrieve it from the ramdisk.

Comment: I presume you meant SFTP server.  Thanks... nice idea :)